# Dynamically updated ng2-charts

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-charts

Is it possible to update any `chart` from `ng2-charts` dynamically? I know there are other libraries like `angular2-highcharts`, but I would like to handle it using `ng2-charts`. Main question is how can I redraw `chart`, after button click? I can resize window and data will be updated, so it have to be any option to do it manually.

https://plnkr.co/edit/fXQTIjONhzeMDYmAWTe1?p=preview

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because link with code for question is no longer valid - question is now useless without the referenced code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figure it out, maybe its not the best existing option, but it works. We can't update existing `chart`, but we can create new one, using our existing `chart` and add new points. We can even get better effect, turning animation of chart off.

<s>Function that solved problem:</s>

```
updateChart(){
   let _dataSets:Array<any> = new Array(this.datasets.length);
   for (let i = 0; i < this.datasets.length; i++) {
      _dataSets[i] = {data: new Array(this.datasets[i].data.length), label: this.datasets[i].label};
      for (let j = 0; j < this.datasets[i].data.length; j++) {
        _dataSets[i].data[j] = this.datasets[i].data[j];
      }
   }
   this.datasets = _dataSets;
}
```

Live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/fXQTIjONhzeMDYmAWTe1?p=preview

**@UPDATE:**
as @Raydelto Hernandez mentioned in comment below, better solution is:

```
updateChart(){
    this.datasets = this.dataset.slice()
}
```

Comment: Your code works, but the same could be accomplished by:  `this.datasets = this.datasets.slice();`

Answer (score 8):

A good way is to get a grip on the chart itself in order to redraw it using the API :

```
export class MyClass {
 @ViewChild( BaseChartDirective ) chart: BaseChartDirective;

  private updateChart(){
   this.chart.ngOnChanges({});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Recently I had to use ng2-charts and i was having a very big issues with updating my data until I found this solution:

```
<div class="chart">
        <canvas baseChart [datasets]="datasets_lines" [labels]="labels_line" [colors]="chartColors" [options]="options" [chartType]="lineChartType">
        </canvas>
</div>
```

and here what I have in my component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'product-detail',
    templateUrl: 'product-detail.component.html'
})

export class ProductDetailComponent {
    @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;

    private datasets_lines: { label: string, backgroundColor: string, borderColor: string, data: Array<any> }[] = [
        {
            label: "Quantities",
            data: Array<any>()
        }
    ];

    private labels_line = Array<any>();

    private options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    };


    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {

        this.getStats();

    }
    getStats() {

        this.labels_line = this.getDates();

        this._statsService.getStatistics(this.startDate, this.endDate, 'comparaison')
            .subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log('getStats success');
                this.stats = res;

                this.datasets_lines = [];

                let arr: any[];
                arr = [];
                for (let stat of this.stats) {
                    arr.push(stat.quantity);
                }

                this.datasets_lines.push({
                    label: 'title',
                    data: arr
                });

                this.refresh_chart();

            },
            err => {
                console.log("getStats failed from component");
            },
            () => {
                console.log('getStats finished');
            });
    }

    refresh_chart() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(this.datasets_lines_copy);
            console.log(this.datasets_lines);
            if (this.chart && this.chart.chart && this.chart.chart.config) {
                this.chart.chart.config.data.labels = this.labels_line;
                this.chart.chart.config.data.datasets = this.datasets_lines;
                this.chart.chart.update();
            }
        });
    }

    getDates() {
        let dateArray: string[] = [];
        let currentDate: Date = new Date();
        currentDate.setTime(this.startDate.getTime());
        let pushed: string;
        for (let i = 1; i < this.daysNum; i++) {
            pushed = currentDate == null ? '' : this._datePipe.transform(currentDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
            dateArray.push(pushed);
            currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        }
        return dateArray;
    }    
}
```

I'm sure this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

### **This worked for me - with pie-chart:*

**Component.html:**

```
 <canvas baseChart [colors]="chartColors" [data]="pieChartData" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"></canvas>
```

**Component.ts:**

In the header section:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
```

In the declaration section of export class:

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;
// for custom colors
public chartColors: Array<any> = [{
backgroundColor: ['rgb(87, 111, 158)', 'yellow', 'pink', 'rgb(102, 151, 185)'],
borderColor: ['white', 'white', 'white', 'white']
}];
```

After the block that updates your pie chart data (using services/sockets or any other means):

```
this.chart.chart.update();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is in 2020 where a schematic exists for [ng2-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts)

```
npm i ng2-charts
ng generate ng2-charts-schematics:<type> <chart-name>
```

This generates a component (eg a bar chart named times-bought)

times-bought.component.html

```
<div style="display: block; width: 40vw; height:80vh">
  <canvas baseChart
    [datasets]="barChartData"
    [labels]="barChartLabels"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [colors]="barChartColors"
    [legend]="barChartLegend"
    [chartType]="barChartType"
    [plugins]="barChartPlugins">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

and in the component ts you subcribe to a service  that returns an observable of the data, in this case we count a firestore Field value which we parse to a number and the title of course/product bought

times-bought.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartDataSets, ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { Color, Label } from 'ng2-charts';
import { AdminService } from 'src/app/services/admin.service';
import { _COURSES, _BAR_CHART_COLORS } from  "../../../../settings/courses.config";//

@Component({
 selector: 'times-bought-chart', // Name this however you want
 templateUrl: './times-bought.component.html', 
 styleUrls: ['./times-bought.component.scss']
})
export class TimesBoughtComponent implements OnInit {

public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
 { data: [0, 0, 0, 0], label: 'Times Bought', barThickness: 60, barPercentage: 0.1 }];
public barChartLabels: Label[] = _COURSES  // Array of strings
public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero: true } }] }
};
public barChartColors: Color[] = _BAR_CHART_COLORS // 
public barChartLegend = true;
public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
public barChartPlugins = [];

constructor(private adminService: AdminService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.adminService.getAllCourses().subscribe(
    data =>{
      this.barChartData[0].data = data.map(v=> parseInt((v.times_bought).toString())) // parse FieldValue to Int
      this.barChartLabels = data.map(v => v.title)
  })
}}
```

the service ts file that performs the actual query to firestore and returns an observable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Course } from '../interfaces/course.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

public  getAllCourses(){
  return this.db.collection<Course>('courses', ref =>
    ref.orderBy('times_bought', 'desc')).valueChanges()
}}
```

and the settings/courses.config.ts

```
export const _COURSES = [
 'Title1',
 'Title2',
 'Title3',
 'Title4']

 export const _BAR_CHART_COLORS = [
 {
   borderColor: [
     'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
     'rgba(54, 75, 181, 0.5)',
     'rgba(114, 155, 59, 0.5)',
     'rgba(102, 59, 155, 0.5)'
   ],
   backgroundColor: [
     'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
     'rgba(54, 75, 181, 0.3)',
     'rgba(114, 155, 59, 0.3)',
     'rgba(102, 59, 155, 0.3)'
   ]
 }]
```

Also be sure to close subscription in ngOnDestroy.
The observable to the courses collection will emit a new value every time the times_bought field is updated and this will trigger the update in the chart.
The only downside with this is that the color is binded to a specific column/bar so if one title surpasses the other only the titles will changes place and y-axis will update accordingly but not the colors
Also  make sure you include node_modules/dist/Chart.min.js to your web manifest(in case of pwa service worker), or as a script in your index.html

Answer (score 1):

Update any chart from `ng2-charts` dynamically is possible. 
Example: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/m3fBiHpKuDgYG6GVdJQD?p=preview

That Angular update chart, variable or reference must change. When you just change value of array element, variables and references not changed. 
[See also Github](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/378).

Comment: Does exactly as question asked. This should not have been voted down.

Comment: @Hutch Imho, this answer does not always works, especially if Angular zones are broken. The OP also stated he was looking for a manual solution, which this answer partially addresses.

Comment: data is changing dynamically but what if I want to change linechartlabels, linechartcolors